# ActiveRecord PGError on Heroku not locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

I am getting an ActiveRecord PGError on Heroku not locally. The error message from the Heroku Logs is:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  column items.user_id does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE ("items".user_id = 4) OR

This code works locally (SQLite) but not on Heroku (postgresql) so I have been reading about the differences. At first I thought that it was a case issue as I recognised that it should be `User_ID` -- but now I'm not sure, it's something about "items" that isn't quite right and I can't work out exactly what it is.

As I said this works absolutely fine on my local machine, it's only on heroku and postgres that the problem comes up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a case issue after all - postgres does (I believe) a downcase on everything before sending it to the db -- my `user_id` was actually called, inexplicably, `User_ID`; after migration everything is working -- thanks to those that helped.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your database does not have the 'user_id' column in the items table. This could be because your migration has not been run recently, or perhaps you have edited an existing migration rather than making a new migration to add this column.

Do you care about your data on heroku at the moment? If not you can use Taps to take whatever you have in your local database and set Heroku's database to a (virtual) synchronized copy of it. On your local machine from your project's directory:

```
heroku db:push
```

This will wipe your heroku database so use this wisely.

Comment: i did do a heroku rake db:migrate, and rather than heroku db:push i did a heroku db:pull to bring down my data and make sure it worked locally, it did, it worked fine locally just not on heroku

Comment: what data type is that column? You're using sqlite locally - try moving to postgres locally so you can see what is going on? Or try heroku db:reset

Comment: its an integer.  I think that going forward i will have to change the development to postgres, i never realised that what heroku used, but for the time being I am pretty sure that if i move to postgres localy all that will happen is that i will have the problem locally.  I could try heroku db:reset but not completely sure why i would i just don't think the problem lies with the data in the database.

Comment: yeah - I had to do the same. If you're on a mac make sure you use homebrew. Good luck.

Comment: many thanks.... i am still left with this problem whether i move to postgres locally or not, if anyone has any ideas....

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the app, using the following command:

```
heroku restart
```